# Java FX 2 CSS Pseudo Classes

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2

How can I create my own CSS **pseudo** classes in Java FX 2?

So that in CSS file I could use this style

```
.MyButton : online{ }
```

In FX 1 it could be done overriding methods like

```
 public long impl_getPseudoClassState() {}
```

but they are now **deprecated** :-(

Is there a new way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't do it. Here is what is stated in [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) about this:

> > At this time, the programming interfaces necessary for a class to
> >     declare support for CSS properties, to convert and load these values
> >     from CSS style sheets into object variables, and to declare and notify
> >     changes to an object's pseudo-classes, are considered internal
> >     interfaces and **are not accessible directly to applications**.

Comment: Will they be accessible in the future?

Answer (score 8):

With the public API of JavaFX 8.0 it is possible to introduce custom css pseudo classes.

- See: [`Node#pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass, boolean)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Node.html#pseudoClassStateChanged%28javafx.css.PseudoClass,%20boolean%29)